# How to fix emmc memory showing 0mb?

Tags: adb, custom-roms, boot-loop, twrp, xolo

Yesterday actually I messed my Xolo Q700. Actually I wanted to install a custom ROM "experia final" on it. But I didn't installed any custom recovery previously. So I installed TWRP recovery using mobile uncle flash it from SDcard. It worked absolutely fine. Then I installed custom ROM but during cache and dalvik wipe stage, I selected advanced wipe and wiped everything including `emmc`. Now my phone stuck in boot animation forever and if I open TWRP it shows "unable to mount e: emmc" and emmc memory showing 0mb. I can't side load ROM using `adb cz`. My phone is not detected via USB cable. Please help me on the issue.